# Collision rectangles not working libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, game-physics

I'm trying to get my collision rectangles to work. To debug some of the problems I've been printing the positions getX() and getY() to determine the positions of my collision boxes. But for some reason it doesn't seem to be updated (constantly saying 0.0, even when bullet is firing).

Here is the Bullet constructor, I initially :

```
public Bullet(float spriteX, float spriteY, int playerDirection){
    this.position = new Vector2(spriteX, spriteY);
    this.bulletDirection = Player.playerDirection;
    try{
        img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bullet-green-icon.png"));
        sprite = new Sprite(img);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    collisionBoxBullet = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
    System.out.println("collision bullet box: x" +collisionBoxBullet.getX());
    System.out.println("collision bullet box: y" +collisionBoxBullet.getY());

}
```

These two printlines evaluate to 0.0 which confuses me, because the bullets coordinates should be based on the coordinates of the sprite. Here it is called in the player class:

```
else if (gip.keyDown(Keys.SPACE)){
            Bullet bullet = new Bullet(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), playerDirection);
            Main.currentBullets.add(bullet);

        }
```

From my knowledge, I'm creating the bullet, creating the bullet sprite, wrapping a rectangle around it. So why is it showing it's rectangle coordinates at 0.0/0.0 where as the sprite's at 250/150.

Here I update the rectangles every time the bullet moves (bullet does move across the screen).

```
public static void update(float dt, ArrayList<Bullet> bullets, SpriteBatch batch){

    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++){
        if (bullets.get(i).bulletDirection == 1){
            bullets.get(i).position.y += bullets.get(i).velocity * dt;
            bullets.get(i).collisionBoxBullet = bullets.get(i).sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
            batch.draw(bullets.get(i).sprite, bullets.get(i).position.x,
                     bullets.get(i).position.y);

        }
        else if (bullets.get(i).bulletDirection == 2){
            bullets.get(i).position.y -= bullets.get(i).velocity * dt;
            batch.draw(bullets.get(i).sprite, bullets.get(i).position.x, 
                 bullets.get(i).position.y);
            bullets.get(i).collisionBoxBullet = bullets.get(i).sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
        }
        else if (bullets.get(i).bulletDirection == 3){
            bullets.get(i).position.x -= bullets.get(i).velocity * dt;
            batch.draw(bullets.get(i).sprite, bullets.get(i).position.x, 
               bullets.get(i).position.y);
            bullets.get(i).collisionBoxBullet = bullets.get(i).sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
        }
        else if (bullets.get(i).bulletDirection == 4){
            bullets.get(i).position.x += bullets.get(i).velocity * dt;
            batch.draw(bullets.get(i).sprite, bullets.get(i).position.x, 
              bullets.get(i).position.y);
            bullets.get(i).collisionBoxBullet = bullets.get(i).sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
        }
```

From what i can tell here, the sprite gets drawn to a new location and then a rectangle is made around it again. Why does it keep saying it's at 0.0/0.0 ?

Comment: Might be misunderstanding something here as I am not familiar with the libraries involved, but in which line of your code are the sprite's x and y position set? All I see is `sprite = new Sprite(img);` Presumably a newly instantiated sprite has x and y == 0.0?

Comment: Oh, woops, forgot to set position of sprite! working now! thanks

(embarassing haha)